# How can I query my MongoDB collection from the browser console?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I'm experimenting with code to insert a record into a MongoDB collection:

```
TimeAndSpace = new Mongo.Collection('timeAndSpace');

if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Template.addTimeSpaceForm.events({
        'submit form': function() {
            event.PreventDefault();
            var city = "Fort Bragg";
            var state = "California";
            var yearin = 1958;
            var yearout = 1959;
            Meteor.call('insertLocationData', city, state, yearin, yearout);
        }
    });

}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    // code to run on server at startup
  });

  Meteor.methods({
    'insertLocationData': function(city, state, yearin, yearout) {
        TimeSpaceCollection.insert({
            ts_city: city,
            ts_state: state,
            ts_yearin: yearin,
            ts_yearout: yearout
        });
    }
});     

}
```

I don't know if this code was successful - it did not throw any errors in the command prompt or in the browser console but, especially since I'm sort of guessing/experimenting about what might work, I want to verify the document was actually inserted before I proceed to the next step of adding non-hardcoded field values.

So: how can I query my MogoDB collection from the browser console?

I tried the following two things:

```
timeAndSpace.find()
return timeAndSpace
```

...but neither show me any data, and most throw errors in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this can help you out.

```
TimeAndSpace.find().fetch()
```

Comment: That seemed to work, as it returned "[]", which indicates the collection is empty. So now the question is, why did my code not work/why did the document not get saved into the collection?

Comment: Why not TimeAndSpace.insert(...) ? Is TimeSpaceCollection some other collection ?

Comment: Good catch; looks like a boo-boo on my part. Ouch!

Comment: Dang! It still shows "[]" after changing it to "TimeAndSpace.insert()"

Comment: try to put the `Meteor.methods` outside `if (Meteor.isServer)` and log something in console within insertLocationData to check if it is called or not?

Comment: I did that, and still no document is being inserted into the collection. Oddly, I did see "'preventDefault' is not a function" or some such err msg a couple of times, but no longer, even though that code is still in there...???

Comment: `'submit form': function(event) { event.preventDefault(); ... } `